# これまでだって似たようなものだった in this sentence

Tags: grammar

speaker was captured and is in midst of  being interrogated.

> 動けない私を、延々と嬲り者にするつもりなのだろう。
>
> ゾッとしない考えだが……よくよく思い返してみれば、**これまでだって**似たようなものだった。
>
> ...ば, seems like more of the same things they've already done to me.

i find it difficult to relate this use of これまでだって as "even これまで" or "これまで also" or some sort of quote.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

だって is "also" here, and これまで is "so far" or "until now". It says what the opponent is trying to do is not only seen now but also just like what it has been so far.

Answer (score 0):

これまでだって in this context includes meaning that she's trying to overcome her's bad feeling with a different point of view, Or to stop further depression by giving up thinking about it.
If you want to use it, mind that it's mostly used in negative situation and aiming to cheer up.
ex 消費税が上がることなんてたいした事じゃないよ、これまでだって不景気だったんだから。
 　これまでだってテストでいい点数だったんだから、次のテストもいい点だろう。